# Django Queryset: get instance by id plus n instances by ordering

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a **Conversation** and a **Message** class (messages are ordered by their timestamp). When I render a conversation I load n messages. Older messages should be loaded via a ajax request on demand.

My initial view queryset is:

```
messages = conversation.message_set.all()[:settings.INITIAL_MSG_LOAD]
```

In my ajax view, I have the pk of the oldest displayed message (oldest_id).

```
messages = []
append_msg = False
append_counter = settings.INITIAL_MSG_LOAD
for message in conversation.message_set.all():
    if append_msg:
        messages.append(message)
        append_counter -= 1
        if append_counter == 0:
            break
    if message.id == oldest_id:
        append_msg = True
```

I'm not really aware of the SQL-queries sent to the database for both of these requests.

Does the database returns all messages in the 2nd request? And is there a more efficient way to get the next set of n messages by given pk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one query, which will be much more efficient:  `conversation.message_set.filter(id__gt=oldest_id)[:settings.INITIAL_MSG_LOAD]`

Explanation: filter `messages` in `conversation` with `id` grater then `oldest_id` limit number of rows by `settings.INITIAL_MSG_LOAD` with default ordering for `messages` by `timestamp`

Comment: Your solution requires sequential ids. But filtering by timestamp instead of the id should result the same queryset.